# Android Facebook sdk is not retrieving some friends album and photo info

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have an Android app that shows friends albums and photos. The problem is that I cannot get some pictures and I cannot figure out why. The code is correct, because with the graph explorer I have the same issue. With Facebook official app I do can se the photos, so I guess it is not a privacy problem. Is there any Facebook bug or android-sdk limitation related to this?

The graph explorer does not give information, it just shows:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

The query is:

```
SELECT aid, description, name FROM album WHERE owner=uid
```

where uid is the user id of one of my friends.

It is not a token permission issue, either, because I have tried with all of them.

Any idea??